# Separate a singly-linked-list such that all odd-numbered nodes appear together, and the even numbered nodes appear together

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Given a singly linked list, group all odd numbered nodes together followed by the even numbered nodes.

You should try to do it in place. The program should run in O(1) space complexity and O(nodes) time complexity.

Example 1:

Input: 1->2->3->4->5->NULL
Output: 1->3->5->2->4->NULL
Example 2:

Input: 2->1->3->5->6->4->7->NULL
Output: 2->3->6->7->1->5->4->NULL
Note:

The relative order inside both the even and odd groups should remain as it was in the input.
The first node is considered odd, the second node even and so on.

I tried looking this question up on StackOverflow, and though I found a lot of answers, none of them answered why my code was breaking. Also, I am using Python3, so I could not understand the code that was written. Specifically, I want to know why my code is not working.

So, I have already written the code for this question. However, when I run this code on my computer it does not work.

My logic is pretty simple. First, I store the value of the second node, as that will be the first node in the even half of my list.

Thereafter, take the value of the first node, and get its pointer to point to the next node of the next node. In the end, we are left with a scenario where the last node is the last node in the odd half of my list.

Since I have stored the first node from the second half of my list, all I need to do now is get the pointer of that last node to point to this first node. I don't return a value because as long as I call the next_node on each node, I should get a different value than what was before.

```
def oddEvenNodes(root_node):    
  #Here I store the value of the second node
  if root_node.next_node is None:
    return root_node
  else:
    second_node=root_node.next_node
    node_val=root_node
    prev_node=root_node

 #This is where the actual removing takes place
   while node_val.next_node.next_node is not None:
      prev_node=node_val
      node_val=node_val.next_node
      prev_node.next_node=prev_node.next_node.next_node
  node_val.next=second_node
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: Create a second list to hold the even nodes. As you go through the original list, remove the even nodes and append them to the second list. When you reach the last odd node, append the evens list to the end.

Comment: Iterate the list nodes and find the length of list. Now keep appending the even nodes to end of the list until you reach the count of nodes equal to length of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the algorithm is correct, but the bug is in the last line:

```
node_val.next=second_node
```

First of all, there is no `next` property; it should be `next_node`. But still, this is only correct when `node_val` is an odd node. When it is an even node, you need to do this assignment for one node further in the list -- the final odd one. And in that case the current one should get `None` as `next_node`.

So, in order to know whether you ended up with an odd or even node, you could introduce a counter. The corrected code would look like this:

```
def oddEvenNodes(root_node):    
    if root_node.next_node is None:
        return root_node # Note: no need for ELSE after a RETURN
    second_node = root_node.next_node
    node_val = root_node
    prev_node = root_node
    count = 0 # Added this counter
    while node_val.next_node.next_node is not None:
        count += 1 # Keep track of odd/even
        prev_node = node_val
        node_val = node_val.next_node
        prev_node.next_node = node_val.next_node # Note: shorter way
    if count % 2: # Need different treatment when node is even
        node_val.next_node.next_node = second_node
        node_val.next_node = None
    else: # For odd node: do what you already did, but with bug-fix
        node_val.next_node = second_node
    return root_node # Add this to be consistent with other RETURN
```